# Change field field value on click

Tags: javascript

I want to supply the user with 3 images, each image will have an associated value:

```
1. left,middle,right
2. middle,left,right
3. left,right,middle
```

I then want to write that value to the text field in a form, so it gets saved when the user clicks submit.

I already have a working form where the user can type in values, `1,2 or 3` but want the text field to be hidden and the user to select an image instead and that update the text field.

Comment: Could you please state that you're using a framework next time?

Comment: Where is the fun in that, I dont have a specific framework in mind. Just so happens upon investigation jQuery is already included in solution therefore it was pure telepathy that Matt found a jQuery solution.

Comment: Why would you then mark Matt's post? He's making use of jQuery, thus limiting you.

Comment: I asked the question, therefore i decide the answer. Surely thats the point.

Comment: Sounds more like you guys know each other #?$!

Comment: aefxx: I don't know him, and how the hell am I limiting him by providing a jQuery solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach an onclick handler to the images, which sets the value attribute of the text field to whatever you want.

Here is something for it in jQuery:

```
<img class="clickable" src="something.jpg" alt="left,middle,right"/>
<img class="clickable" src="something.jpg" alt="middle,left,right"/>
<img class="clickable" src="something.jpg" alt="left,right,middle"/>
<input type="hidden" id="clicked-image" name="something"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickable').bind('click', function () {
    $('#clicked-image').val($(this).attr('alt'));
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hardly abusing in my opinion... The values are accurate representations of the images.

Answer (score 1):

Set `@id` attribute to your hidden inputs, and then at your images you can use javascript code, for example

```
<img src="1.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('inputID').value='your value'">
<input type="hidden" id="inputID" name="somename">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery:

```
<img class="selector123" src="..." rel="1"/>
```

in jQuery

```
$(".selector123").click(function(){
  $("#value123input").val($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

That's one example:)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes this a trivial task. You can bind the click event to the images.

excerpt:

```
    <img src="/images/lmr.png" class="direction" name="left,middle,right" />
    <img src="/images/mlr.png" class="direction" name="middle,left,right" />
    <img src="/images/lrm.png" class="direction" name="left,right,middle" />


  <input type="text" value="Click an image" />

<script>
    $('.direction').click(function () {
      var text = $(this).attr('name');
      $("input").val(text);
    });
</script>
```

Tested locally, and the input type field gets its value set. Now you can make it hidden and it will be posted. `(<input type="hidden" etc.)`